# Is ubuntu 20.04 server ram usage less than desktop

Tags: server, ram, lxde

if I installed Ubuntu 20.04 server on an old computer with lxde desktop is the ram usage less than ubuntu 20.04 desktop ?

Can you tell me how much ram it will use ?

Sorry if my English is not good

Thanks

Comment: The LXDE desktop uses *deprecated* GTK2 toolkit/library, and will the most efficient if you're using GTK2 apps (*there aren't many of those! as most GTK apps are GTK3 in 20.04*) so yes will use less RAM, but that will be lost/wasted if using GTK3 or Qt5 apps.

Comment: What will you gain with knowing how much RAM a desktop itself uses?  Lubuntu stopped providing that [here](https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/) as it meant very little.  If using a LXDE desktop, but you use a GTK3 app; you'll be wasting RAM & resources needing different libs/tk for desktop & apps instead of sharing.  LXDE *devs* abandoned GTK3 as blogged about due to its weight, LXDE aimed for Light - which was accomplished with the switch to LXQt as replacement (joining with Razor-Qt *devs*).  LXDE is light when used with GTK2 apps, or no apps at all.  Also what is an old computer?

Comment: How about lxqt , my old computer has core 2 duo and 2gb of ram

Comment: This is a Q&A site and not a Forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums, and https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ is Lubuntu specifically).  I use a `lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)` for QA-testing Lubuntu & other Ubuntu *flavors* but that's off-topic for your question (*this isn't a forum but a Q&A site*) & hardware specs aren't all I'd use to decide what to install.  I use devices from 2006 & newer in QA (my desktop now is a c2q running Lubuntu *kinetic*) so yes Lubuntu will install, but consider everything involved in deciding what's best for you.

Comment: fyi;  some devices (*including the one I mentioned in prior comment*) are listed in this [Lubuntu thread](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-recommended-specs/2984/3)... the thread itself maybe of interest  ... but Yes Ubuntu Server uses less RAM than Ubuntu Desktop. even with LXDE you'll use less RAM than Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) - but that's with nothing running, thus so what??  It's only part of the equation that matters (ie. will you be using additional apps on the desktop itself? ie. those must be considered to know what's best...)